# How can I get text from a cell using the select statement of the query function in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I try to get some data from tab A to tab B using the query function. This all works fine untill I include some data of tab B into the object in the query function.

The thing is, I want to create a scoring sheet that calculates the constructor points based of the first sheet with the driver standings. So tab A looks something like this:

1. Peter Wright - Team Fast Racers - 85
2. Cameron Bright - Team Quickies - 60
3. Marc Feiner - Team Fast Racers - 20

In this example the number correspond to a total amount of points on the right column.

The second tab needing to calculate the constructor points, looks simply like this:

1. Team Fast Racers    105
2. Team Quickies       60

Don't look at the amounts. It is just an example.

Now I want to use the query code where I can ask Google Sheets to grab the constructor name from tab B (i.e. Team Fast Racers) and look it up in tab A to get the score from both drivers and sum it up to get the total. This is the syntax now:

```
=QUERY({'Driver Standings'!$A$4:$T$32; 'Constructor Standings'!A1:C16}; "SELECT T WHERE C = 'B2'", 1)
```

The problem is that it does not recognize B2 to get the 'Team Fast Racers' name and search for it in tab A. How can I fix this problem.

Again, 2 drivers are in a team and those scores need to be summed up and displayed in the second tab to get a clean constructor championship standings. How can I get the data from tab A based on searching for a string out of tab B column B.

And if that is all done, I would also like the constructor standings (tab B) to be sorted based on amount of points, without losing the structure of the formulas.

Comment: It looks like a mess now but I hope someone can figure it out for me!

Comment: Are you talking about `C` and `B` in `Driver Standings` or `Constructor Standings`? It would be easier to understand your issue if you could provide your spreadsheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JVaudM3uTftg4Xw1tVxl3powIzJjxX63dj8PYqp1pfw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, all ranges in `{ }` needs to be of the same size (at least in one dimension). if you are stacking ranges one under another then amount of columns needs to be the same:

```
{Sheet1!A:C; Sheet2!A:C}
```

---

then when you have a "constructed range" as above, you need to use `Col` references in `QUERY` statement

so instead of

```
"select A,C"
```

it needs to be

```
"select Col1,Col3"
```

---

then if B2 is a numeric number it will be

```
"where Col1 = "&B2
```

but if it is a plain text it will be:

```
"where Col1 = '"&B2&"'"
```

---

## UPDATE:

tho all you need is:

```
=QUERY({'Driver Standings'!C4:C\'Driver Standings'!T4:T}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2)
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  order by sum(Col2) desc 
  label sum(Col2)''")
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JVaudM3uTftg4Xw1tVxl3powIzJjxX63dj8PYqp1pfw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try to edit the sheet untill it works? I feel you will have it sorted out quickly. And can you make the Constructor Standings tab also sort based on points like the driver standing?

Comment: The Sheet is View Only

Comment: Should be fixed now. Thanks again

Comment: Uhm yeah but for example Tulip Racing now has 85 points. But that is from just 1 driver. It should contain the points combined of 2 drivers. So 151 I believe

Comment: @MattKing you helped me the other day with this question, but could you please help with my latest question? I am sure you can figure it out ;)